# Count distinct over partition by

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, window-functions

I am trying to do a distinct count of names partitioned over their roles. So, in the example below: I have a table with the names and the person's role.

I would like a role count column that gives the total number of distinct people in that role. For example, the role manager comes up four times but there are only 3 distinct people for that role - Sam comes up again on a different date.

If I remove the date column, it works fine using:

```
select
a.date,
a.Name,
a.Role,
count(a.Role) over (partition by a.Role) as Role_Count

from table a

group by a.date, a.name, a.role
```

Including the date column then makes it count the total roles rather than by distinct name (which I know I haven't identified in the partition). Giving 4 managers and 3 analysts.

How do I fix this?

Desired output:

| Date | Name | Role | Role_Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01 | Sam | Manager | 3 |
| 02/01 | Sam | Manager | 3 |
| 01/01 | John | Manager | 3 |
| 01/01 | Dan | Manager | 3 |
| 01/01 | Bob | Analyst | 2 |
| 02/01 | Bob | Analyst | 2 |
| 01/01 | Mike | Analyst | 2 |

Current output:

| Date | Name | Role | Role_Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01 | Sam | Manager | 4 |
| 02/01 | Sam | Manager | 4 |
| 01/01 | John | Manager | 4 |
| 01/01 | Dan | Manager | 4 |
| 01/01 | Bob | Analyst | 3 |
| 02/01 | Bob | Analyst | 3 |
| 01/01 | Mike | Analyst | 3 |

Comment: `COUNT(DISTINCT a.Name) ...` instead of `count(a.Role)`

Comment: @gofr `COUNT(DISTINCT...) OVER...` not available in SQL Server`

Comment: @Charlieface Oh, they still didn't make anything with it... My bad

Comment: Wait let me get this straight: How does `Sam` have Role_count 3 if there are only two rows? Putting it another way: why are you using window aggregates at all, why not regular aggregates? Can we have sample input data?

Comment: @Charlieface I want the total distinct people in that role. So Sam appears twice on two different dates, but there are still only 3 unique managers regardless of how many times he shows up. The sample data is the same table without the role count column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, SQL Server (and other databases as well) don't support `COUNT(DISTINCT)` as a window function.  Fortunately, there is a simple trick to work around this -- the sum of `DENSE_RANK()`s minus one:

```
select a.Name, a.Role,
       (dense_rank() over (partition by a.Role order by a.Name asc) +
        dense_rank() over (partition by a.Role order by a.Name desc) -
        1
       ) as distinct_names_in_role
from table a
group by a.name, a.role
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. This works fine when there are only unique names. The date columns duplicate the names many times and so causes this dense rank count to overcount by the number of duplications. I have added a.date in my example code to clarify

Comment: @BaronG . . . No.  This works.  That is the point of it replacing `COUNT(DISTINCT)`.  If you set up a db<>fiddle, I can illustrate it.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, `COUNT(DISTINCT` is not available as a window aggregate. But we can use a combination of `DENSE_RANK` and `MAX` to simulate it:

```sql
select

a.Name,
a.Role,
MAX(rnk) OVER (PARTITION BY date, Role) as Role_Count

from (
    SELECT *,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY date, Role ORDER BY Name) AS rnk
    FROM table
) a
```

If `Name` may have nulls then we need to take that into account:

```sql
select

a.Name,
a.Role,
MAX(CASE WHEN Name IS NOT NULL THEN rnk END) OVER (PARTITION BY date, Role) as Role_Count

from (
    SELECT *,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY date, Role, CASE WHEN Name IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ORDER BY Name) AS rnk
    FROM table
) a
```

Comment: Hi, I need uniqueness with the a.date column also.

Comment: OK I think you got that now